# Getting space between navbar list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a navbar but have problem getting space between the list items. I tried using `justify-content: space-between`; but it didnt solve it. Im using CSS flexbox and this is how I did it:

```css
.NorMenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="NorMenu">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Logo</a></div>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="elements.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Just add margarin, I mean margin. For example `li { margin: 0 10px; }` also the div cannot follow `ul`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much space you need but you have too many flex nesting and seems unnecessary. I removed the flex properties on the `nav`.

Your html was also invalid as `ul` cannot contain `div` tags

The issue before was you nested 2 flex elements making the 2nd element becoming a flex child of the first flex container and the first flex container had justify-content space between effectively making your second flex container(flex child of first container) width less than 100%

```css
.NorMenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="NorMenu">
      <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="elements.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

```css
.NorMenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}   

li a {
  color: red;
}

ul{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="NorMenu">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Logo</a></div>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="elements.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid.

Comment: @Rob why the HTML in that case is invalid? 
will be for the reason of having a div inside the ul element??

Comment: `ul` cannot contain `div`

Comment: @AlbertinoCarvalho Yes. Only `<li>` can be the children of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

just set `width: 100%` for '.NorMenu' class.

```css
.NorMenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li {
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

li a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="NorMenu">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Logo</a></div>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="elements.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```